# Multiple .css files in child theme

Tags: html, wordpress, css

First working with child themes in WP.

I created a new folder in themes folder with the name my-theme-name-child and placed style.css file which works.

Now, the original theme has a responsive stylesheet which is located in my-theme-name/css/layout.css how do I replicate this in my child theme?

I created the folder css in my child theme and created layout.css there like this:

```
@import url("../my-original-theme/css/layout.css");

@media only screen and (min-width: 769px)

#header {
    padding: 20.618em 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: post your Folder structure.

Comment: there is post structure in my question

Comment: Pratik, this is for you:
original theme: www.myweb.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme
child theme: www.myweb.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme-child

the responsive css is located here: www.myweb.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/css/layout.css

I have located the layout file in my childs theme like this: www.myweb.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme-child/css/layout

I have tried placing the file in the root of the child theme but the styles are not recognized from there.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd load the stylesheets directly instead. Open up functions.php inside your child theme and add the following code:

```
function wpse_load_parent_stylesheets() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'layout', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/layout.css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_load_parent_stylesheets' );
```

Repeat wp_enqueue_style for each stylesheet you want to load.

Comment: I use this function and still it does not work. My folder and file structure is exactly like pevoje. I used the answer below, also does not work. What might be wrong?

Comment: @Navid This is the correct answer to the question asked. If it isn't working for you, that doesn't mean that it's wrong. It means that you have a different problem. The answer below mine for instance references the stylesheet directory which doesn't solve the problem posed by the question.

Answer (score 4):

After creating `layout.css` in the css folder of your child theme, you will have to write the below function in **child theme's `function.php`**, in order to load it:

```
function load_child_stylesheet() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'layout', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/layout.css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_child_stylesheet' );
```

You can refer [this](http://wisdmlabs.com/blog/wordpress-child-theme-not-loading-stylesheet/) article which talks of a similar issue

Comment: agree with @WisdmLabs.To note that get_template_directory_uri return parent theme directory and get_stylesheet_directory_uri return child theme directory